# How do I get all of the gallery post in mysql in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, gallery

I am trying to write a query for getting all of the category gallery post  in wp.  I tried smth like this:

`SELECT ID, post_title, post_excerpt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'`

but I am not sure. So How can i get a list of all pages from gallery, with images, titles, content ? thx

Comment: You mean you need to create a wordpress query that you'll display on frontend or? Because you can use `$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
);` and then just call `WP_Query()` with `$query_images = new WP_Query( $args );`.

Comment: I need a wp query which will be display on phpmyadmin. I do not want to write code in php for that. I just want the mysql query. I want to get all of the pages using the category id or descriptor from gallery

Comment: Oh you need pure php, that's totally different then.

Comment: Are u telling that there is no query for that ? I must use PHP ?

Comment: Maybe there is, the only thing that comes to my mind is to use `set_option` to write to `wp_options` table inside the database. I don't know that you can use a query to display anything on phpmyadmin, or what you'll do with that information. Unless you're thinking of wordpress backend, and not [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)...